# if statement not working, python

Tags: python, if-statement

This code asks user for choice of 1 or 2. If 1, then blahblah; if 2 then blahblah. If neither, then repeat until 1 or 2 is entered. Program does not accept 1 or 2, instead going straight to 'else' and repeating input question to enter 1 or 2.

```
def optionType ():         # pick option

#pdb.set_trace()

    option = ''
    print ('Which slice option do you want, even slice (1) or leftover(2)? ')
    input (option)

    if option == '1':
        evenSlice()        #includes decimal

    elif option == '2':
        leftoverSlice()    #omits decimal

    else:
        print('Enter either 1 or 2.')
        optionType()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Step one: print `option`. Step two: look at what's printed (in this case, option wasn't assigned the input which becomes fairly obvious using this basic method of debugging). Posting on SO should be step 42 or something :p

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I would guess 3 based on the `print('Enter...` statement (though that doesn't guarantee anything)

Comment: Yeah, because it would work just fine in 2.x as well.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: judging by the other questions asked by this user so far, it's Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the return value of the [`input()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

```
option = input('Which slice option do you want, even slice (1) or leftover(2)? ')
```

The function argument is the text you want to display, not the variable you want to receive the user input.

Comment: Well, that's step one, but the `if` still won't work because he'll end up comparing a string to an int.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- Not in python3.x (which based on the parens with print is a valid possibility)

Comment: Is that so...darn, thought I had you there Maritjn :P

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to store the option

   `option = input('Which slice option do you want? even slice (1) or leftover(2)?')`

And if you are on Python2 ( but not Python3 ) :

1. when you do that, if someone passes in 1, it will be an int, not a string.

   `if option == 1:`
2. so `input` will cause an error if a letter is typed in [ http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input ] , you probably want `raw_input`

   `option = raw_input('Which slice option do you want? even slice (1) or leftover(2)?')`

Comment: `raw_input` is Python 2 only. The OP appears to be using Python 3, where `input()` returns a string, always.

Comment: i didn't know that about python3. thanks!  impossible to tell what the OP is using though.

Comment: Well, looking at the other questions the OP asked, where a python version is given it's Python 3.